# Magento setting up conditional sale on products

Tags: magento, product

Ok I need to know if the following is possible to do, Lets say i have a product called A, but i want some other products lets say x and y to be on sale, but you can only buy X and or Y if you already purchased A.

Is there any way one can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to segregate the two set of products i.e (Type 1 : Product A (can be purchased without any dependent product) , Type 2 : Product X and Y (needs to have Product A in cart). This segregation can be best done by defining an attribute that does this job. Let's say we create an attribute Sell Individually and set it to Yes for Product A and set it to No for Product X and Y.

Now, you will need to listen to the event : checkout_cart_save_before, in this observer you will write the code that will control whether a particular product can be added to the cart or not.

You can refer to this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) to read more about using Magento Events and Observer.

Comment: This is good. But do not just check adds, but also removes/updates because this is to be avoided : I add A to cart, then X, then in cart I change qty of X to 10 or I just remove A.